# React router did not match any route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i trying to make some basic examples with `react-router` but it just doesn't works. The code and the idea are simples:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import App from './App';
import About from './About';
import Repos from './Repos';
// import NotMatch from './NotMatch';

export default class RouterApp extends Router {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={ browserHistory }>
        <Route path='/' component={ App } >
          <IndexRoute component={ Repos } />
          <Route path='about' component={ About } />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

It renders the `App` component, but any other route doesn't works, like `http://localhost:8080/#/about?_k=nwt0sq`, that route throw's me: `Location "/about" did not match any routes`.

The `Repos` route (indexRoute) doesn't works too.

BTW, this is the `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import RouterApp from './modules/Router'

render(<RouterApp/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Any idea? I was reading another questions and googling around but can't solve this.

Here are my Components:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return <h1> APP </h1>;
    }
}
```

Repos.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Repos extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <section>
                <h2>Repos</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>Repo 1</li>
                    <li>Repo 2</li>
                    <li>Repo 3</li>
                    <li>Repo 4</li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

About.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class About extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <section>
                <h2>About</h2>
                <p>
                    Pariatur eum tenetur in iste maiores est architecto dignissimos. 
                    Vero non explicabo veniam quam debitis. 
                    Deleniti rerum eaque ratione provident delectus architecto veniam. 
                    Ipsum omnis dicta eum dolore ea.
                </p>
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be way off base here, but. Your router is using push-state history (by the attribute history = {browserHistory}) but the url you listed as an example is using hash-based routing (/#/about). That may not work correctly. If you are manually navigating to your about page try doing it without the hash. Also try not adding any query string params either

Comment: @PaulStoner weird because the hash is automatically set when I open the path.

Edit: i changed to hashHistory but the problem is still there.

Comment: My apologies, then. I was making that comment based off of a similar looking router I setup. Adding the hash to the route, when manually navigating to my about page, caused the browser to not transition. I'll look to see if I can find anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got your mistake, your route doesn't actually specify a path.you need to put slash for every path like this:-

```
 render() {
    return (
      <Router history={ browserHistory }>
        <Route path='/' component={ App } >
          <IndexRoute component={ Repos } />
          <Route path='/about' component={ About } />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

Comment: As i know, the trailing slash isn't required in the child routes, btw i tried it and got the same error :/

Comment: the base route setting the path to "/" takes care of that. In my limited experience the routes themselves don't require the leading "/"

Comment: In your base component are you returning children props

Comment: You need to return this.props.children from App.js like this :-

Comment: render() {
        return(<div> <h1> APP </h1>{this.props.children}</div>);
    }

Comment: That was all, i didn't use the this.props.children

Answer (score 0):

try refactoring your app.js as follows:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<div> (this.props.children} </div>):
    }
}
```

you need to pass down the routes to your main app component.