# Why is Link to not working in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using `react-router` and `Link to` function. I want to show `second component` on button click  but my code is not working

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GNadKZ?editors=1010

```
var Router = ReactRouter;

var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var Link = Router.Link;
var Route = Router.Route;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

class Abc extends React.Component {
  handle(){
    alert('move to second component')
  }
   render (){
     return (<div><h1>second</h1><Link to="about"><button onClick={this.handle}>move to second page</button></Link></div>);

   }
}
class Pqr extends React.Component {
   render (){
     return (<div><h1>second</h1><button>click</button></div>)

   }
}

ReactDOM.render((<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Abc}>
      <Route path="about" component={Pqr}/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>),document.getElementById('root'));
```

There is a button in the first component. I want to show second component on button click.

Comment: please share first component

Comment: already share in code pen

Comment: You should close out your other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318668/how-to-move-one-component-to-another-component-on-button-click-in-react

Answer (score 0):

Declare `{this.props.children}` in first component's render

```
 return (<div><h1>second</h1><Link to="about"><button onClick={this.handle}>move to second page</button></Link> {this.props.children} </div>);
```

check if it's working:

```
var Router = ReactRouter;

var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var Link = Router.Link;
var Route = Router.Route;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

class Abc extends React.Component {
  handle(){
    alert('move to second component')
  }
   render (){
     console.log('inside first render');
     return (<div><h1>second</h1><Link to="about"><button onClick={this.handle}>move to second page</button></Link>{this.props.children}</div>);

   }
}
class Pqr extends React.Component {
   render (){
     return (<div><h1>second</h1><button>click</button></div>)

   }
}

ReactDOM.render((<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Abc}>
      <Route path="about" component={Pqr}/>  
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
     </Route>   
  </Router>),document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: what are changes ?

Comment: yes why `Mo match` component not found ..I remove this line pls see code pen

Comment: A few days back, i wrote an answer please go through it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41269708/react-router-did-not-match-any-route/41270379?noredirect=1#comment69742504_41270379